# Old data being overwritten - Python to Excel

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I currently have a registration system where I want the user's details to be stored in an excel file. The code below allows the user's details to be stored in the excel file, however, once new details are inputted, the old data gets overwritten with the new data. I am using OpenPyxl. I have been searching online for an answer but have found nothing. Can someone please advise me as to what is going wrong.

```
    def excel():
      row = sheet.max_row
      column = sheet.max_column
      sheet.cell(row = row + 1, column =1).value = firstname.get()
      sheet.cell(row = row + 1, column= 2).value = lastname.get()
      sheet.cell(row = row + 1, column=3).value = username.get()
      sheet.cell(row = row + 1, column = 4).value = password.get()
      workbook.save(filename="Students Details.xlsx")
```

I have also added an image of my excel database below. Everything in row 2 is overwritten when new data is inputted. I want it to move onto row 3 and so on.

[image: Excel Database]

Thank you :)

Comment: You should probably check what sheet.max_row is returning. But basically just use append() as described in the documentation.

Comment: Hi Charlie, its returning 1.